# Is there a way to get links to a google drive video file with redirector.googlevideo.com?

Tags: json, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I used to get links for video streams from google drive file like this:
https://r10---sn-3c27ln7s.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=74dd098b62525d54&itag=18&source=webdrive&app=docs&ip=188.163.98.118&ipbits=8&expire=1442346818&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=397C18F3AE6C610474D08C488D5AF100ED216BFA.F0054EA555A89D47246A4D7940737FE31A4F3EF&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-3c27ln7s&ms=nxu&mt=1442343170&mv=m&pl=18&type=video/mp4
but now they've became IP-tied and dont work.

Is there a way to get links to a google drive video file like this:
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=7190d1270ce7b390&itag=22&source=webdrive&cmo=secure_transport=yes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1442433811&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=3A6A4C31E6E72FD2476E70D5C1DC15034E246B0.E62179AC670E5B501EF27BDF81BFC4DF5EC9159&key=ck2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following link to embed videos and images. Just give a try.

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileID}
```

Comment: it gives me a download link. it's not what was needed, butt thank you for effords.

Comment: Necro'ing this post in 2024, no longer works.

Comment: For Images, try thumbnail URL, https://drive.google.com/a/thumbnail?id={fileID}&sz=s200.png
For Videos, try embedding URL @JoshHibschman

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
  https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<YOUR-ID-HERE>
```

Beware this.

If you call with Method GET - You get a file

If you call with Method POST - You get a JSON return with something like this

```html
{
"disposition": "SCAN_CLEAN",
"downloadUrl": "https://doc-0o-2g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securescxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx?e=download",
"fileName": "VID_20170508_085207.mp4",
"scanResult": "OK",
"sizeBytes": 31851745
}
```

Comment: Necro'ing this post in 2024, no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

If your video files are above 100mb then you can use this :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file id}?alt=media&key={drive api key}
```

You can get your drive api key here :

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://docs.google.com/e/yourdomain.com/get_video_info?docid={doc_id}`.
Change **yourdomain.com** to your domain gsuite.

Fetch the api using the url with your access_token. If not using access token maybe you will get 403 forbidden access.

Comment: what do you mean by domain gsuite? is it possible to do so without this?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "Fetch the api using the url with your access_token" ? do you mean but the [server side] service token in the headers?

Comment: What do you mean

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following link to get the video stream from google drive:

`http://api.getlinkdrive.com/getlink?url={google_drive_url}`