# Get original link from direct link Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I want get original link Google Drive from the url:

`https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=ck2&nh=IgpwcjA1LmhrZzAxKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mn=sn-i3b7kn7k&mm=31&ipbits=32&source=webdrive&ip=2001:ee0:305:1::11&signature=B0518B1D616EC0933D669F69C194CCC358B69E76.998F3A6DB7EE8F284801EB115064C0D4FD4D007D&ttl=transient&requiressl=yes&expire=1479880338&itag=37&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&pl=48&id=4f2c2017ed76b08d&mv=u&ms=au&app=explorer&mt=1479865862&filename=video.mp4`

But seem Google Drive API doesn't support. Anyone help me...

Best Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608289/is-there-a-way-to-get-links-to-a-google-drive-video-file-with-redirector-googlev

Answer (score 0):

The Drive API allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. Also, you can [download Google Documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads) (Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, etc.) and export them to formats that your app can handle. Drive also supports providing users direct access to a file via a link.

To download files, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For example:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs`

The response contains the link in the downloadUrl field. For example:

`{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0B0iTh2ZTRkNjI1ZjUtOGIwZS00YzhiLWJmMWMtNWI4YzY3NzQyNWQ2",
 "downloadUrl": "https://doc-04-c1-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ivearmirmg66&e=download&gd=true",
 ...
}`

Here are examples of performing a file download with our Drive API client libraries: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#examples